# Android OnTouch method value unable to initialized

Tags: android, ontouch

In my application I want to calculate the ratio between two distance, but I don't know why the variable dist1 and dist2 are not save the value that I have calculated in the IF ELSE statement, what is wrong in my coding?

Any guidance or help will be appreciated.

This is the method coding:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    float x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2, dist1, dist2;
    int pointerIndex;

    if(event.getPointerCount()==1){
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
        } else {
            pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
        }
        mRenderer.setXY(x, y);
        requestRender();
    }
    if(event.getPointerCount()==2){
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            x1 = event.getX(0);
            y1 = event.getY(0);
        }else {
            x1 = event.getX(0);
            y1 = event.getY(0);
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            x2 = event.getX(1);
            y2 = event.getY(1);
            dist1 = (float)Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
            Log.v("DIST1: ", String.valueOf(dist1));
        } else {
            x2 = event.getX(1);
            y2 = event.getY(1);
            dist2 = (float)Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
            Log.v("DIST2: ", String.valueOf(dist2));
        }
        ratio = dist2/dist1;//here the dist2 and dist1 is not initialized
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: well all i see is either dist1 or dist2 gets initialized, never both. So you will always have a zero division problem.

Comment: The dist1 and dist2 is in red text and not to initialized

Comment: follow your if else logic. IF action is pointer down SET dist1 only, otherwise SET dist2 only. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I think you need to make dist1 and dist2 members of the surrounding class.

Comment: If I put the dist2 formula in IF statement then the dist2 variable is able to use and also same for the dist1. if I did like this I can't get the before distance and what I get dist1 and dist2 are the same value which is the after distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set `dist1` and `dist2` from two separate touch events. You have declared these two variables within the `onTouchEvent()` method. As soon as this method returns the variables go out of scope and cease to exist.

What you need to do is declare them somewhere that will persist over multiple touch events. The easiest way to do this is to declare them as members of the surrounding class.

```
private float dist1, dist2;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2; // Do not re-declare dist1 and dist2 here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but I dunno why must set dist1 and dist2 to global?

Comment: @KenChong Because otherwise they only exist inside that method call. Every time a touch event occurs, all the variables are re created. When the method finishes, all its variables are destroyed.